# How to configure https_check URL in nagios

Tags: linux, url, https, nagios, nagiosxi

I have installed Nagios (Nagios® Core™ Version 4.2.2) in Linux Server.I have written a JIRA URL check using check_http for HTTPS url.

It should get a response 200, but It gives response HTTP CODE 302.

```
[demuc1dv48:/pkg/vdcrz/Nagios/libexec][orarz]# ./check_http -I xx.xx.xx  -u https://xxx.xxx.xxx.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa -S CONNECT
SSL Version: TLSv1
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 302 Found - 296 bytes in 0.134 second response time |time=0.134254s;;;0.000000 size=296B;;;
```

So I configured the same in the nagios configuration file.

```
define command{
        command_name    check_https_jira_prod
        command_line    $USER1$/check_http -I xxx.xxx.xxx.com  -u https://xxx.xxx.xxx.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa -S CONNECT -e 'HTTP/1.1 302'
}
```

Now my JIRA server is down, But it is not reflected in the nagios check.The nagios response still shows HTTP code 302 only.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You need to follow both answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify, but I assume you defined your command in the Nagios central server `commands.cfg`configuration file, but you also need to define a service in `services.cfg` as services use commands to run scripts.

If you are running your `check_http`check from a different server you also need to define it in the `nrpe.cfg` configuration file on that remote machine and then restart `nrpe`.

As a side note, from the output you've shared, I believe you're not using the flags that the `check_http` Nagios plugin supports correctly. 
From your post:

```
check_http -I xxx.xxx.xxx.com  -u https://xxx.xxx.xxx.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa -S CONNECT -e 'HTTP/1.1 302'
```

From `./check_http -h`:

```
-I, --IP-address=ADDRESS
    IP address or name (use numeric address if possible to bypass DNS lookup).
```

You are using a host name instead (xxx.xxx.xxx.com )

```
-S, --ssl=VERSION
    Connect via SSL. Port defaults to 443. VERSION is optional, and prevents auto-negotiation (1 = TLSv1, 2 = SSLv2, 3 = SSLv3).
```

You specified `CONNECT`

Comment: Im running this check_http from my nagios machine, The JIRA URL is running in another machine. `./check_http -I <<jira ip address>> -u https://jira-ex.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa -S` , the Output is `CRITICAL - Socket timeout`. But the URL is up and running now

Comment: @user2439278 were you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get code 200 unless you set `follow` parameter in `chech_http` script.

I suggest you to use something like this:

```
./check_http -I jira-ex.telefonica.de  -u https://xxx.xxx.xxx.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa -S -f follow
```

The `-f follow` is mandatory for your use case as that page/webserver returns `302` status response code which indicates that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the *Location* header and you should *follow* that redirection to get a destination code.

Comment: Can you explain why  you think it's mandatory ?

Comment: Added explanation.